# Javascript IBAN Validation. Check german or austrian IBAN

Tags: javascript, validation, iban

i want to validate a german or a austrian iban.

```
['validate-IBAN', 'Please enter a valid IBAN.', function (v) {

     var pass=v.strip();
     if (0 == pass.length) {
         return true;
     }
     if (!(/[AT || DE]\w{2}/i.test(v)) || !(/[0-9]\w{18 || 20}/.test(v))) {
         return false;
     }
     return !(pass.length < 20);

        }],
```

I want to check an german IBAN like DE19 1234 1234 1234 1234 12 (two letters and 20numbers) or an
austrian IBAN like AT6119043002345732201 (2letters and 18 numbers)

But it doesnt work. What is wrong?

Thanks a lot (-:

Comment: Try https://github.com/arhs/iban.js

Answer (score 0):

You've invented a new regex syntax, but you forgot to tell the Javascript maintainer to implement it. There nothing like `[AT || DE]` nor `\w{18 || 20}`.

You need to:

- first drop all spaces
- check the regex `/DE\d{20}|AT\d{18}/`
- [check the sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Validating_the_IBAN)

I guess, checking the sum is the most important part as it prevents users from entering nonsense by mistake.

As noted in a comment, there is a [ready to use script](https://github.com/arhs/iban.js/blob/master/iban.js) for this available. However, I found it too complicated as they prevent too improbable errors (an IBAN with a wrong structure, but a correct checksum). I just wrote a simple function myself

```
isValid: function(x) {
    if (x.length < 5) return false;
    if (!x.match(/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]+/)) return false;
    var ASCII_0 = "0".charCodeAt(0);
    var ASCII_A = "A".charCodeAt(0);
    var acc = 0;
    function add(n) {
        if (acc > 1000000) acc %= 97;
        acc = n < ASCII_A ? 10 * acc + n - ASCII_0 
            : 100 * acc + n - ASCII_A + 10;
    }
    for (var i=4; i<x.length; ++i) add(x.charCodeAt(i));
    for (var i=0; i<4; ++i) add(x.charCodeAt(i));
    acc %= 97;
    return acc == 1;
},
```